# Showing validation errors for specific input field

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, file-upload

I have a form set up with a file upload for profile pictures, and I'm validating the file upload like so:

```
'picture' => array(
    'kosher' => array(
        'rule' => 'validateImage',
        'message' => 'Only images are allowed to be uploaded'
    ),
    'size' => array(
        'rule' => array('fileSize', '<=', '2MB'),
        'message' => 'Picture must be less than 2 MB'
    )
)
```

The validation runs, and works, however no validation errors are shown on the form when I submit incorrect data. I'm building the entire form like so:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Profile', array('type' => 'file')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->hidden('id'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->label('Profile.picture', 'Profile picture'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->file('picture'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('firstname'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('lastname'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('email', array('between' => 'This is the email other users will use to contact you')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Skill', array('type' => 'text', 'value' => $skills, 'label' => 'Your skills (seperate each skill by space)')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('course'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('bio'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Save changes'); ?>
```

The other fields error messages get shown correctly, just not the file upload. How can I make the validation errors show up around the file input?

Comment: `'picture'` is defined as an array for `<?php echo $this->Form->file('picture'); ?>` but not `size`. Far as I can tell.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying?

Comment: Your `'size'` is not being echo'ed anywhere, as compared to `'picture'`, `'firstname'` etc. Isn't the error message for the file upload `'message' => 'Picture must be less than 2 MB'`?

Comment: Maybe you need to add `<?php echo $this->Form->file('size'); ?>` somewhere. Then again, I may be wrong.

Comment: show validate action for 'validateImage'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `$this->Form->file('picture');` which will only generate the file upload field nothing else.

Either add a `$this->Form->error('picture');` below it which will show the validation error message or use `$this->Form->input('picture', array('type' => 'file'));` to generate the file upload input also.

`Form::input()` is a wrapper method which generates the required input field, label tag and shows validation error message if any. Please read the manual.

Comment: You'll probably have to specify the type of input to use for the 'picture' field, because the CakePHP FormHelper will not automatically create `file` inputs; i.e. `echo $this->Form->input('picture', array('type' => 'file'));`

Comment: Right, forgot to mention this. Need to specify the `'type' => 'file'` as it cannot be automatically inferred. I updated my original answer accordingly.